# Discord.py: Is it possible to add commands to the right-click context window ("Apps")?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I couldn't find anything about this in the discord.py docs. Any ideas how we can add commands in the context menu (right-click) under "Apps"?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Those are called [context menu commands](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html?highlight=context_menu#discord.app_commands.context_menu).

They are called like this:

```py
@tree.context_menu(name="your_name")
async def your_command_func(interaction: discord.Interaction, message: discord.Message):
    pass #interaction is as per usual, message is the selected message
```

You can add an extra check (like check for admin rights or specific role) with `@app_commands.check()` right before defining the function.